# webkit layout engine for android and ios

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, webkit, mobile-webkit

I want to implement a layout engine in `c++` leverage the power of `html/css` for IOS and android. Yes, a cross platform view in `html/css`, the same time with the native speed.

Of course I firstly think about `webkit`, why not using `webkit/webcore` to implement what I want. But when I dig into the webcore code. I got that split the layout stuff from webkit is not an easy job.

**Are there some projects is doing what I want?**

**If no, anyone can give me some suggestions?**